# Accessing ItemsPresenter items in a ListBox

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, vb.net, xaml

I need to iterate through the VirtualizingStackPanel of a ListBox control to get at the `ListBoxItem.RenderSize` values. In C# of VB.NET code, how might that be done?

Background:

I'm working with a third party control library in WPF which apparently has bugs (or "features") related to its Measure() algorithms. Instead, it does a very non-standard attached Dependency Property to size one of its frames.

To get around that I'm overriding Measure and supplying my own values to the attached property, but the values are being eaten by intervening values in the visual tree. However, the Items property of my ListBox returns viewmodels, which don't contain sizing info. Neither does the template for the viewmodel, which must auto-size.

Comment: You may access the container of an item (i.e. the ListBoxItem) by calling the [ContainerFromItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemcontainergenerator.containerfromitem.aspx) method of the ListBox's [ItemContainerGenerator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemcontainergenerator.aspx)

Comment: Calling that function on the ViewModel in the `ListBox.Items` collection returns `Nothing`

Comment: Well, then you're somehow doing it wrong. `ContainerFromItem` will give you the `ListBoxItem` that holds an item, provided that the item is contained in the ListBox's Items collection, and that the corresponding ListBoxItem has already been created. Maybe the ListBoxItem has not yet been created due to virtualization.

Comment: Of course I'm doing it wrong; it's what has prompted the question in the first place. And of course virtualization is in play, it's a default-templated `ListBox`.

Comment: As far as I can read your question, you haven't explicitly asked about ItemContainerGenerator. Anyway, you may post some here.

Comment: When your requirement is to have all item containers generated immediately (which would be necessary for the iterating you asked for), you may consider to disable virtualization.

Comment: Even with virtualization disabled (replaced it with a StackPanel) I'm still getting Nothing from ContainerFromItem

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing any code...

Answer (score 0):

If container is not created (i.e., it is out of viewport bounds), you have to get the ScrollViewer which is the ListBox template child and then call the ScrollToHorisontalOffset method to create containers for items. After that you should also call the UpdateLayout to force container generation - here you can acces newly created container. Note that in has no correct value for RenderSize, but you can measure element and get its DesiredSize.

Note that ContainerFromItem can return null if your listbox is collapsed or container generation is not started (or not finished) - check the ItemContainerGenerator.Status property.

Comment: A code sample would go a long way to my understanding this answer. I suspect that I'm trying to do these Measures before the listbox visual elements are generated.